# how to create IDbDataParameter with null-able value?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have add a null value to parameter list for inserting values to a table, which accepts some null values. Here is my example codes:

```
 bool sql = true;
 // ....
 List<IDbDataParameter> parameters = new List<IDbDataParmeter>();
 // adding values...
 object objVal = 1;
 parameters.Add(
    sql ? new SqlParameter("@colIntA", objVal) : 
          new OracleParamer(":colIntA", objVal));
 // this would not work, what should I add?
 objVal = string.Empty;
 parameters.Add(
    sql ? new SqlParameter("@colIntB", objVal) : 
          new OracleParamer(":colIntB", objVal));
```

Not sure if I have use db specific DbNull value and is that also SQL or Oracle specific?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to assign an empty string ('') to an int parameter there, so yeah, that's not going to work.

To represent a database-independent null value, use [DbNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx).

```
 new SqlParameter("colIntB", DbNull.Value)
```

(Note that I've left off the "@", which works in my experience with Sqlparameters. I'm not sure whether you can do the same with the ":" for Oracle.)

One extra tip: Use your connection to create the command, and the command to create the parameters. That will create instances of the right class depending on the type of the underlying connection:

```
IDbConnection conn = sql ? new SqlConnection(...) : new OracleConnection(...);

// this will give you either an SqlCommand or an OracleCommand
IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

// this will give you either an SqlParameter or an OracleParameter
IDbDataParameter param1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
param1.ParameterName = "colIntB";
param1.Value = objVal;

cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
```

Comment: Very interesting point on getting parameter. If I have a list of parameters, I may need to create a loop to create, set name, set value and set direction if needed. Thanks!

Comment: David - also take a look at my AddInputParameters extension method. Makes things really easy: http://www.madprops.org/blog/adding-idbcommand-parameters-with-anonymous-types/

Comment: actually in the class where parameter is created in my case, there is no IdbConnection nor IDbCommand is available. I have a SQLParameter class for creating collection of IDbDataParameter. I do have information about sql or oracle. Can I create a dummy connection and use it get parameters?

Comment: OK. Both SqlConnection and OracleConnection have new() CTOR. I guess I can it as dummy connection to get IdbCommand and then IdbDataParameter, am I right or exception would be thrown?

Comment: No, I wouldn't create a dummy connection. If you don't know the connection/command details at the time you're creating the parameters then your current method is probably safest. Can you not pass the command into the method that creates the parameters?

Comment: Thanks for your information. I separate parameter and connection in two different classes. I could pass connection in for creating parameters, however, since I only deal with sql and oracle cases, it is ok as-they-are.

Answer (score 1):

Use DbNull.Value. That will work for any ADO.NET-compatible data source (both SQL and Oracle providers), as it is the responsibility of the provider to know what to do when it encounters a DbNull value.